# sql query to run based on a column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with below values for database : db1

```
database   sync_status     validation    remark
db1        successful      failed        error
db1        successful      successful    all is well
```

I don't want the query to return any row, if the validation is successful for database db1. But in my case it is returning the row with failed validation.

```
select database,sync_status,validation,remark from bcv_sync where database='db1'  and validation!='successful' and validation='failed' and rownum = 1;
```

But if in case the db1 validation is failed the query must return the row with failed validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one success means the database is successful, then you can use aggregation.  I'm not sure what you want in the other columns, but this may do what you need:

```
select database, max(sync_status), max(validation), max(remark)
from bcv_sync
where database = 'db1' 
group by database
having sum(case when validation = 'success' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: What if there is more than one database (db2, db3, ...) - presumably the OP would want results for the other databases as well?

Comment: @mathguy . . . Then the op would omit the `where` line altogether (the `group by` would have a different line for each "database") or would use `in` with a list of databases.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your cryptic question then you want to show the rows that failed only if there is not a row that succeeded:

```
SELECT database,
       sync_status,
       validation,
       remark
FROM   (
  SELECT d.*,
         COUNT( CASE validation WHEN 'successful' THEN 1 END ) OVER ()
           AS num_success
  FROM   db1 d
)
WHERE  validation = 'failed'
AND    num_success = 0;
```

Comment: If there is more than one database (not shown by the OP, he only has 'db1'), then it would make sense to "COUNT" over (partition by database). I think...